# ことになる vs. ことになる, contextwise

Tags: expressions

In the grammar sections of my textbook, I learnt that

SENTENCE + ことになる

Expresses that SENTENCE has been decided.

However, in this context, it seems more like ことになる indicates that there is/was a change of state.

> このように私たちが幸せな生活ができれば、私のゴールを果たしたことになります。
>   "If we can all lead a happy life this way, it will be that I have achieved my goal."

If I regard なります as representing present tense, then I could imagine the "decision" semantics working to a degree, but it would make less sense:

"If wen can all lead a happy life this way, I decide that I have achieved my goal."

Again, since my textbook only taught me that ことになる expresses a decision, I wanted to ask for clarification/confirmation in this case.

Comment: Also related: [How to translate ことになる in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48607/5010)