# What is the meaning of にならない in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

I came across the following sentence while watching the video "Japanese conversation with YUSUKE san YUYU NIHONGO (No1)", at [the timestamp 16:05](https://youtu.be/I3xEzd1ehKY?t=965):

> それは大阪のおばあちゃんはのぞくにならない

The context is the following: She was talking about how Japanese people care about dressing their age, and a 30 year old person would not dress in a colorful manner because otherwise people would look at them weird, and then he said the aforementioned quote. She laughs and says they're an exception. Based on that I can assume he is saying Osaka grandmas are an exception, but I don't know how にならない works here. I think the verb would be 除く since it would make sense. But I don't know what nuance does にならない add. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have difficulty hearing the difference between おばちゃん and おばあちゃん.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> それは「大阪のおばちゃんは除く」にならない？
>
> Doesn't it <sub>(=your statement)</sub> come with "Excluding Osakan obachan"?
> Don't you say "Except for Osakan obachan" too?

- それ refers to her previous statement.
- Here "大阪のおばちゃんは除く" is treated as a quote. Note that he's saying おばちゃん (middle-aged woman, usu. 35–60), not おばあちゃん (grandma, usu. > 60).
- ～になる here is "to amount to", "to end up with", or "to (effectively) mean". You may already know this as part of ことになる.

  - [How do ことになる and ようになる differ? (When ことになる cannot = "It has been decided that")](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17954/5010)
  - [How to translate ことになる in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48607/5010)

  This sentence is roughly the same as "大阪のおばちゃんは除くことにならない?", but here こと is not used because the "excluding ～" part is presented as an independent quote rather than a nominalized clause. The idea is that when someone states something like "a 30-year-old Japanese person would not dress in a colorful manner", they would usually be expected to add "Excluding Osakan obachan" as well. Of course, it's a joke.
- ならない is pronounced with rising intonation, so this ならない is a question.