# う/る＋ことになる construction

Tags: grammar

So, I have an exercise which has 3 sets of sentences. The 1st one is supposed to be translated using ことになる, the 2nd - using ことになった, and the 3rd - ことになっている. The construction itself is pretty understandable. It means that something was decided not by a speaker, but by circumstances or by somebody else. I get it and there's nothing difficult but... let me show you 3 sentences, 1 from each set so you could get the idea:

> **1** The time difference between Moscow and Tokyo is 6 hours which means that it's now 11 p.m. in Tokyo.
>
> **2** It was decided that we all go to Kyoto.
>
> **3** Classes last until 2 p.m.

2 and 3 are easy to translate but I can't understand how to translate the 1st one

> **1** -------
>
> **2** 私達は京都で会うことになった。
>
> **3** 授業が午後２時までつづくことになっている。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the translation of sentence number 2, in its current state, the statement itself *may* be true (It sounds like "It has been predetermined: we will meet at Kyoto."), but since the trip was decided in the past, the translation should have「～へ行くことになった」or something similar.

In sentence number 1, the "which means that" is the part that corresponds to「～ということになる」. In this way,「～ことになる」is also used to indicate a logical conclusion. [Here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17963/34007) it's used in a related manner.

Comment: wait, so I can add 「という」and then go for the aforementioned construction? didn't know that. will check the link, thank you!